# How should I perform this sql query in laravel? I am having difficulties from the start

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How should I perform this sql query in laravel? I am having problem from the start.

```
select buy.buyer,buy.buysum,sale.seller,sale.salesum,buy.buysum + sale.salesum as "Total" from
(select buyer,sum(amount) as "buysum" from tbl
group by buyer) buy
inner join
(select seller,sum(amount) as "salesum" from tbl
group by buyer) sale 
on buy.buyer=sale.seller
order by total DESC
limit 5
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Please include any error messages of the symptoms of the problem.

Comment: I have only been able to this much and separately  
$top1=DB::table('tb')
              ->select(DB::raw('buyer,sum(amount)'))
                     ->groupBy('buyer')
         
              ->get();

              dd($top1);
              exit();
  $top2=DB::table('tb')
              ->select(DB::raw('seller,sum(amount)'))
                     ->groupBy('seller')
              ->get();

              dd($top2);
              exit();

Comment: When I have complicated select queries I generally just use `$result = DB::select('...')`. Unless there's an overarching reason to go via Eloquent.